# "Duck typing" etymology?

Tags: duck-typing

Is there a story behind the name ''duck typing'', I've heard ''if it looks like a duck, and sounds like a duck, let's call it a duck'' (or something like that), but why a duck? Why not ``if it looks like a _ and sounds like a _, let's call it a _''.

It sounds like a Flying Circus sketch, but I don't remember it. Is there a story behind the name?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about a practical programming problem, as laid out in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Duck typing is a phrase borrowed from the much older "walk like a duck".  The latter has been around far longer than the programming idea it describes.  See [answerbag.com](http://www.answerbag.com/q_view/32573)

Answer (score 3):

http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/msg/e230ca916be58835?hl=en&

Alex is involved... ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is not really a programming question, but my guess: Ducks walk funny and they quack.  This is amusing enough to turn it into a figure of speech.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Quoting Wikipedia's [article on Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing):

> The name of the concept refers to the duck test, attributed to [James
>   Whitcomb Riley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Whitcomb_Riley), which may be phrased as follows: "When I see a
>   bird that walks like a duck and swims like a duck and quacks like a
>   duck, I call that bird a duck."

...and from the same page...

> [Alex Martelli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alex_Martelli) made an early (2000) use of the term in a message
>   to the comp.lang.python newsgroup. He also highlighted
>   misunderstanding of the literal duck test, which may indicate that the
>   term was already in use:
>
> *"In other words, don't check whether it IS-a duck: check whether it
>   QUACKS-like-a duck, WALKS-like-a duck, etc, etc, depending on exactly
>   what subset of duck-like behaviour you need to play your
>   language-games with."*

Answer (score 0):

No, the analogy is that if a variable looks like an integer (for example), and acts as an integer, it must be an integer (type).

Duck typing means 'no explicit predeclaraction of type'.

Comment: I get that, but I'm wondering why duck, of all possible choices

Comment: well, as everyone agrees, we know the expression about ducks, it's been around for a while. Possibly, the characteristics of a ducks *easily* distinguishes it from other waterfowl. The story of the Ugly Duckling must be the exception which proves the rule.